# React.js and big table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to draw a big table, not really big, about 400x400 cells. But React renders it too slow, and on every click on the cell, cell should be updated and this update takes same huge amount of time. Any suggestions how to speed it up ? Or React is just not suitable tool for such task ?

Here is example (with slightly reduced size of table):
https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/15731/

```
var ROWSC = 400;
var COLSC = 100;

var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            t: { "1-1": 'c' }
        };
    },
    clicked: function (k) {
        var t = this.state.t;
        t[k] = t[k] ? 0 : 'c';
        this.setState({  t: t  });
    },
    render: function() {
        var items = [];
        for (var r = 0; r < ROWSC; r++) {
            var cols = [];
            for (var c = 0; c < COLSC; c++) {
                var k  = ''+r+'-'+c;
                cols.push(<td key={c} onClick={this.clicked.bind(this,k)} className={this.state.t[k]}>&nbsp;</td>);
            }
            items.push(<tr key={r}>{cols}</tr>);
        }
        return <table>
            {items}
            </table>
        </div>;
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Well you can see that this is O(n^2), 400*100 is not so big but it still is. If you decrease it on 50*50 you'll immediately see the difference. There is an interesting speed comparison at this link but still react beats the other stuff:https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/reactjs-vs-angular-js-performance-comparison-knockout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, React re-renders everything, but in the presence of performance problems, 
it is possible to use the [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) function to determine which parts
of the component tree to exclude on updates.

In your example, there is only a single row that can be updated at once, so
if we start tracking which row the update occured on we can make sure only
this row is updated. First, we must introduce a new component that wraps the
table row where we can place our hook.

```
var Row = React.createClass({
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps) {
        return nextProps.mustUpdate;
    },
    render: function() {
        return <tr>{this.props.children}</tr>;
    }
});
```

Then we can use it like

```
items.push(
   <Row key={r}
        mustUpdate={this.state.lastUpdatedRow === r}>
        {cols}
   </Row>);
```

Furthermore, it seems like a waste to re-render all those cells too, so we can introduce
yet another component that wraps the table cells.

```
var Cell = React.createClass({
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps) {
        return this.props.selected !== nextProps.selected;
    },
    render: function() {
        var props = this.props;
        return (
            <td onClick={props.onClick.bind(null, props.col, props.row)} 
                className={props.selected ? 'c' : ''}>&nbsp;
            </td>
        );
    }
});
```

This should give you a significant performance improvement on updates. If it is still not
good enough for your particular problem, it might be that React is not ideal for your use case.
Anyway, that is the essence of optimizing React programs, you split components into smaller
components and make sure only the parts that actually changed update.

Comment: Extracting some markup to components with `shouldComponentUpdate` improved speed significantly, but it is still slower than jQuery implementation. So it comes out React does not fit here.

Comment: @Dfr ok, I see. For illustration purposes, here is the same example showing how to fall back to raw DOM manipulation in React. This might be useful if a component has certain performance characteristics where raw DOM manipulation makes most sense or you need to integrate with another DOM library. https://jsfiddle.net/treap/yoLhbzsj/

Answer (score 0):

While I was reviewing your results in the console, I noticed the following popped up on each jsfiddle run:

`You are using the in-browser JSX transformer. Be sure to precompile your JSX for production - http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#jsx`

I followed the link and saw that the documentation warns about performance impacts when using the in-browser JSX transformer:

`The in-browser JSX transformer is fairly large and results in extraneous computation client-side that can be avoided. Do not use it in production`

Perhaps doing another test with JSX precompilation would give you a better idea about whether this is a good use case for React.

Comment: Just for completeness here is non-JSX variant: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/15760/

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

Make sure to precompile JSX to avoid that slowness. (In the jsfiddle, you'll see a console warning "You are using the in-browser JSX transformer. Be sure to precompile your JSX for production".

Being implemented as a single Component with click setting state on itself, causes the component to have to re-process the entire table (because `setState` triggers `render` which rebuilds the table DOM). You can avoid much of this by creating a Component to represent each table cell. Then in your `clicked` function, instead of calling setState on `Hello`, just call `setState` on the cell that was clicked. That way only the cell that changed will re-render.

This doesn't help the initial render, but it will significantly speed up UI updates due to clicks.