# React/Redux Application complete re-renders on changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, electron

so I am working on a project to display data in React/Redux.

Data gets received over an tcp socket and instantly dispatched into the store.
My problem roots in the re-rendering of my applikation as soon as my store state changes.

```
    function mapStateToProbs(state){
    return{
        ApplicationProcess: state.ApplicationProcess,
        SubSchedule: state.SubSchedule,
        Command: state.Command,
        CommandParameter: state.CommandParameter
    }
}

//pulling needed actions for dispatchign store
function mapDispachToProbs(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
}
    @connect(mapStateToProbs, mapDispachToProbs)
    @debugRender
    export default class Body extends React.Component{


        render(){
            //inline CSS block
            const divTable = {
                overflow: "auto",
                willChange: "transform",
                maxHeight: "20em"
            }

            const stayRight={
                float: "right"
            }

            //Basic Body with 3 Tables and their layout, passing down the data need to fill Tables
            return(
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="container-fluid"><Header hideCols={this.props.hideCols} subSchedule={this.props.SubSchedule} command={this.props.Command} applicationProcess={this.props.ApplicationProcess} /></div>
                    <div className="container-fluid"><Meta metadata = {this.props.CommandParameter}/></div>

                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                                <div className="row"><div className="col-md-10 text-center h5"> Sub-Schedules </div></div>
                                    <div className="row" style={divTable}>
                                        <Table tabledata={this.props.SubSchedule} sortTable={this.props.sortTable} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <div className="col-md-2 col-sm-10" style={stayRight}>
                                <div className="row"><div className="col-md-12 text-center h5">Enabled APIDs</div> </div>
                                    <div className="row" style={divTable}>
                                        <Table tabledata={this.props.ApplicationProcess} sortTable={this.props.sortTable} />
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <div className="row"><div className="col-md-12 text-center h5">Commands</div></div>
                                <div className="row" style={divTable}>
                                    <Table tabledata={this.props.Command} sortTable={this.props.sortTable} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                                <div className="row"><div className="col-md-10 text-center h5"> Sub-Schedules </div></div>
                                <div className="row" style={divTable}>
                                    <Tabledos tabledata={this.props.SubSchedule} sortTable={this.props.sortTable} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-2 col-sm-10" style={stayRight}>
                                <div className="row"><div className="col-md-12 text-center h5">Enabled APIDs</div> </div>
                                <div className="row" style={divTable}>
                                    <Tabledos tabledata={this.props.ApplicationProcess} sortTable={this.props.sortTable} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <div className="row"><div className="col-md-12 text-center h5">Commands</div></div>
                                <div className="row" style={divTable}>
                                    <Tabledos tabledata={this.props.Command} sortTable={this.props.sortTable} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                )

        }
    }
```

This is my Body Compenent. Dont wonder that I dupicated the tables, since the first three tables do everything in one component. Creating the thead with my cols, the tbody with my rows and managing the everything about my table. 
I know that this isn't best practice with react so I changed alot and seperated everything into components. The secound table only got a TableHead and TableBody Component:

```
@debugRender
export default class Table extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const { 
                tableHead,
                tableBody,
                DataType
                } = this.props.tabledata


        return(

                <table className="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
                    <TableHead tableHead = {tableHead} DataType = {DataType}/>
                    <TableBody tableBody = {tableBody} />
                </table>
            )
    }


}
```

And the TableHead will create Columns:

```
export default class TableHead extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state={
            columns: this.props.tableHead

        }
    }

    eachColumn(col, i){
        var uid = this.props.DataType + '_' + col,
            visibility = this.state.columns.byCol[col].visibility,
            col = visibility ?
                 <Columnn key={uid} id={uid} data={this.state.columns.byCol[col]}/> 
                : null

        return(
                col
            )
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        var arr = {...this.state.columns, ...nextProps.tableHead}
        //console.log(arr)
        this.setState({columns: arr})

    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        if(this.props.tableHead.byCol !== nextProps.tableHead.byCol){
            console.log("return true")
            return true
        }
        console.log("return false")
        return false
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.state)
        const{
            columns
        } = this.state
        return(
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {columns.allCols.map(this.eachColumn.bind(this))}
                </tr>
            </thead>
        )
    }



}
```

And each Column is basicly this:

```
export default class Column extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const th = {
            backgroundColor: "#8c918d",
            width: "auto",
            whiteSpace: "nowrap"
        }
            return(
                <th id={this.props.id} 
                className="sticky-top" 
                style={th}>
                {this.props.data.name}
                </th>
            )
    }
}
```

If I dispatch now anyaction, for example set the visibility of any column to false, not only my whole table will  re-render, my body and all ther components in it will re-render as well. Thats something I cannot understand. Maybe anyone can help me with this.

PS: Any advice on best practice when working with react/redux is wellcome.

EDIT: 
To be clear, I have 3 Tables in my view and I didnt want to do 3 seperate components for the same task. Since all tables will have the same options, only the data that I display will change. Everything else should be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Redux is making your componente state change. When a component state change (by change, not necessaray has to be a difference in it), React is gonna re-render to verify if there is updates to do in DOM (he made that by comparing the old virtual DOM with the new which he mounted). You can optimize you component returning false to shouldComponentUpdate, by doing that you previne the call of re-render:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return false;
}
```

but, you have to know exactly if nothing changes to you component, otherwise things will get out of control in DOM.

This all you con get in the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#avoid-reconciliation) to optimize React

Comment: I don' really understand your answer. Where would I put the shouldCompenentUpdate return false function? I know that my Component will update regulary, so returning a default false would be not what I want.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Returning a default false is never the solution. You have to compare some data that you know is gonna change, and if it changed, you return true, otherwise return false.

Comment: You checked out my code? That's what im doing. But the problem is, that my body component, which gets the props from the redux store, is re-rendering every single time. 

I thought that I just pass the props down to the component that will get the changes and only that one will re-render. but it re-renders everything inside the body.

Comment: This occurs because the props was connected in the body component. So your body component have this props. When redux change, this props will change, so React will re-render, even so you component dos't use it (just pass it down). For example, if you have a father component to this body component, this father do not get rerender because he doesn't have relation with the child props.

Comment: Ok that what i can understad. But now my question on that topic:

My tables can have up to 5000 rows with up to 20 columns. 
I have 3 Tables at a time. So i have to make a component for every single table and connect them indivisually? or every go further and creat a component and connect it to even smaller parts of my store? Because rerendering 5000x20 html elements seems not the way that should work

Comment: You have these options you said. But maybe you can put a wisely Cell and Row component, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530928/react-js-and-big-table